# duplicate URLs issues how to implement it in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have duplicate URLs for every page on my website, like this:

https://maindomain.com/index.php?store/ubuy=34&hta&ext=.html ( i want to 301 redirect to this url ( as an example: https://maindomain.com/store/ubuy=34.html)

This link is the one I want it to stay without index.php? or &hta&ext

I can not add all more than 5000 urls to htaccess file to 301 redirect to the correct page,

what are the rules in .htaccess i should be add to fix this issues?